# How to extract the content of two equal XML-fields with XSLT?

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt

I have the following fields in XML:

```
<datafield tag="004R"><subfield code="0">10900/69470</subfield></datafield>

<datafield tag="004R"><subfield code="0">10419/140630</subfield></datafield>
```

So  the Tags are the same "004R" and also the subfiledcode "0", but the value is different.

I try to extract both fields with my XSLT, but I get only the first repeated twice. That's my XSLT:
First I define the variable

```
<xsl:variable name="handle004R" 
                        select="recordData/record/datafield[@tag='004R']/subfield[@code='0']" />
```

and then try to extract all the values:

```
 <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="string($handle004R)">
                            <xsl:for-each select="$handle004R">
                                <identifier xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$handle004R" />
                                </identifier>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise />
                    </xsl:choose>
```

The output is:

```
<identifier xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">10900/69470</identifier>
<identifier xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">10900/69470</identifier>
```

But it should be:

```
<identifier xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">10900/69470</identifier>
<identifier xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">10419/140630</identifier>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<xsl:value-of select="$handle004R" />` to `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.

Comment: This change leads to error message: Couldn't compile the stylesheet. Error by checking the type of the expression "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.ForEach@22e0f643".'

Comment: Which tool gives that error, for which line exactly? Did the code you posted work? Can you post a minimal but complete XSLT and XML sample that did not give errors?

Comment: `compiler.ForEach` suggests the error is earlier with the `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Your solution is working now. Thanks a lot. That was my fault.